# How can change text of title when tab bootstarp was been active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a tab bootstarp and a title for my page and I want to change the title of page with click on tab is active but my jquery code donot work correctly.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.chooseChangePass li a', function(e) {
  if ($("#chPass").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#TitlePage").html("change Password");
  } else {
    $("#TitlePage").html("change UserName");
  }
  
  if ($("#chUserName").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#TitlePage").html("change UserName");
  } else {
    $("#TitlePage").html("change Password ");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="TitlePage">change password</h1>
<ul class="chooseChangePass">
  <li class="active" id="chPass"><a href="#changePassword" data-toggle="tab">change password</a></li>
  <li id="chUserName"><a href="#changeUserName" data-toggle="tab">change UserName</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="changeUserName">
    changeUserName
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="changePassword">
    changePassword
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing code, that toggles `active` class. Add bootstrap.min.js file. Also, `else` statements in your code are redundant.

Correct way of changing page title after tab changes is to use [Bootstrap navs events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#events). You need to listen for `shown.bs.tab` event.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $('#page-title').html(e.target.text);
});
```

Here's working example with Bootstrap 4.1.3: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrJOQE?editors=1010

Be sure to lookup documentation for Boostrap version that you are using, as there were significant changes between version 3 and 4. And change tab selector to named one, if you are planning to have more tab groups on same page.